# How do I reduce the line spacing in XCeed WPF Extended Toolkit Richtextbox

Tags: c#, richtextbox

I am using the WPF Extended Toolkit Richtextbox to display simple text. But the lines are widely separated rather than one after the other. Indentation appears to be working OK. It's just that 5 lines of text takes up a lot of space. I tried setting Margin="0." I cannot find a property to set such as "Line Spacing" to set.

```
        <tools:RichTextBox Grid.Row="3"
                       Grid.Column="1"
                       Text="{Binding Procedure}"
                       Margin="0"
                       ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                       BorderBrush="Gray"
                       BorderThickness="2"
                       Padding="0"
                       AcceptsReturn="True"
                       AcceptsTab="True"
                       AllowDrop="True"
                       AutoWordSelection="True"
                       >
        <tools:RichTextBox.TextFormatter>
            <tools:PlainTextFormatter/>
        </tools:RichTextBox.TextFormatter>
    </tools:RichTextBox>
```

The Document property can not be set with a binding.

Comment: Post your code so others can replicate the issue and understand it better!

Comment: Shahin - It doesn't have code. It is an object, a control. It is the Extended WPF Toolkit Rich Text Box. The code can be found on Git Hub. The line spacing is obviously a part of the object. Adding <tools:RichTextBox> to my post is not going to help get an answer from someone familiar with the control. Add the control to any XAML UI. It is like adding <Textblock>.

Comment: Adding `<tools:RichTextBox />` only won't help you display text either, because you can set it by either using the Text property, or the Document property from code-behind as far as I can tell, and I don't know which you are using. When I used Text, the indentation behaved differently than when doing `myRtb.Document.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(new Run("my long string")));` from code-behind. It's always a good idea to post the code, and even a screenshot of what you see / what you want to see, then people can help you quickly and efficiently. We should always value other peoples' time :-)

Answer (score 0):

Line spacing cannot be formatted using the rtf header with the `Text` attribute in the extended wpf richtextbox. Use the `Block.LineHeight` attribute instead. It has to be about 130-150% of the font size to work.

```
<xctk:RichTextBox Block.LineHeight="20"/>
```